# Solving perturbed quantum harmonic oscillator

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, harmonic-oscillator, perturbation-theory

I am trying to solve the following perturbed Hamiltonian

$$
H = H_0 + H' = \frac{\omega}{2}\Big(a^{\dagger}a + 1\Big) + \lambda \frac{\omega}{2}\Big(a^{\dagger}a^{\dagger}+aa\Big),
$$
namely, I am trying to determine eigenvalues and eigenvectors. Here $h'$ is a perturbation, namely $\lambda<<1$. After some calculations with the ladders operators
$$
\begin{cases}
a = \sqrt{\frac{m\omega}{2\hbar}}\Big(x+\frac{i}{m\omega}p\Big)\\
a^{\dagger} = \sqrt{\frac{m\omega}{2\hbar}}\Big(x-\frac{i}{m\omega}p\Big)
\end{cases}
$$
where, in this case, $\hbar = m = 1$, I found out that this Hamiltonian can be written as follows
$$
H = \frac{\omega}{2}\Big[(1+\lambda \omega)x^2+(1-\frac{\lambda}{\omega})p^2\Big]
$$
at the same time we could rewrite $H_0$ as
$$
H_0 = \frac{\omega}{2}\Big[x^2+p^2\Big]
$$
so, basically, what it takes to transform $H_0$ into $H$ is the transformation
$$
\begin{cases}
x \longrightarrow \sqrt{1+\lambda \omega} ~~x \sim (1+\lambda \frac{\omega}{2} )x\\
p \longrightarrow \sqrt{1-\frac{\lambda}{\omega}}~~ p \sim (1-\lambda \frac{1}{2\omega})p
\end{cases}.
$$

I hope what I did so far was useful.

Now I am stuck and pretty much I don't see how to actually go on and compute the eigenvectors and eigenvalues, my intuition is that we have to transform the solutions to the standard QHO, how could I procede solving it?

Comment: Do you know how to find the eigenstates of the standard QHO? Have you gone through the steps before?

Comment: yes, I basically can use this formula $|n> = \frac{(a^{\dagger})^n}{\sqrt{n!}}|0>$ knowing that they are ladder operators

Comment: Good. So, as long as you are able to define some new $b$, $b^\dagger$ in terms of your perturbed coefficients of $x^2$ and $p^2$ you will be good to go. Right? You just need to carefully track the coefficients.

Comment: Yes, if I manage to show that they are also ladder operators. Ok while writing it I understood that this is pretty much it, basically just prove that they are ladder operators and everything else will be the same as the unperturbed oscillator. Right?

Comment: Note that this model breaks down when $\lambda >\omega$, because that makes the momentum term negative.

Comment: ok sure, I specified that $\lambda <<1$

Comment: Actually, now I'm a little confused about the units.  It seems like $\lambda$ should be unitless, but then you've got the term $1-\lambda/\omega$.  Are there some hidden unit assumptions here?

Comment: @CosmasZachos Nah, the units should still work out even if we assign different units.  Up there, the first term has "units" of $[\omega]$ and the second has units of $[\omega][\lambda]$.  Mathematically, we can't simplify this into a form where we get something like $1-\lambda/\omega$.  Something went wrong with the algebra.  I get the following:  $$\frac{\omega}{4}+\left(\frac{1}{4}-\frac{\lambda }{2}\right) \hat{p}^2+\left(\frac{1}{4}+\frac{\lambda}{2}\right)\omega^2\hat{x}^2$$.

Comment: @march Right your are. My eye missed what he had actually written! I instinctively absorb junk units into the variables, precisely to avoid this bedlam! Why he doesn't set ω=1 I have no clue.

Answer (score 1):

First, let's dispense with a little of the algebra.  When I apply the transformation from the raising and lowering operators back into the original momentum and position operators, I get the following Hamiltonian:
$$
\hat{H} = \frac{\omega}{4}\hat{I}+\left(\frac{1}{4}-\frac{\lambda }{2}\right) \hat{p}^2+\left(\frac{1}{4}+\frac{\lambda}{2}\right)\omega^2\hat{x}^2\,.
$$
Now, we can diagonalize this using the following transformations:
\begin{align}
\hat{x}&=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\omega}}\left(\frac{1-2\lambda}{1+2\lambda}\right)^{1/4}\left(\hat{b}+\hat{b}^{\dagger}\right)\,,\\
\hat{p}&=i\sqrt{\frac{\omega}{2}}\left(\frac{1+2\lambda}{1-2\lambda}\right)^{1/4}\left(\hat{b}^{\dagger}-\hat{b}\right)\,.
\end{align}
The result is
$$
\frac{\omega}{2}\sqrt{1-4\lambda^2}\hat{b}^{\dagger}\hat{b}+\frac{\omega}{4}\left(1+\sqrt{1-4\lambda^2}\right)\hat{I}\,.
$$
In this form, the eigenvalues are apparent.  If we need to write the eigenvectors in terms of the *original* basis, we'll have to do more work.